# Error con librería Apache POI

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, apache-poi

Estoy trabajando con excel desde java, utilizando apache POI y me esta lanzando el siguiente error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLException:
>   org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.setEntityExpansionLimit(I)Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions;
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:657)
>     at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:180)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.(XSSFWorkbook.java:286)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.(XSSFWorkbook.java:307)
>     at main.MainExcel.writeXLSXFile(MainExcel.java:32)  at
>   main.MainExcel.main(MainExcel.java:20) Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:56)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:63)
>     ... 6 more Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.setEntityExpansionLimit(I)Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions;
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLTypeLoader.(POIXMLTypeLoader.java:43)
>     at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.ThemesTable.(ThemesTable.java:86)
>     ... 12 more

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;


public class MainExcel {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        writeXLSXFile(5, 6);



    }

    public static void writeXLSXFile(int row, int col) throws IOException {
        try {
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("ruta_archivo.xlsx");


            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            Cell cell = null;

            XSSFRow sheetrow = sheet.getRow(row);
            if(sheetrow == null){
                sheetrow = sheet.createRow(row);
            }

            cell = sheetrow.getCell(col);
            if(cell == null){
                cell = sheetrow.createCell(col);
            }
            cell.setCellValue("Pass");

            file.close();

            FileOutputStream outFile =new FileOutputStream(new File("ruta_archivo 2.xlsx"));
            workbook.write(outFile);
            outFile.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();


        }
    }

}
```

No tengo muy claro porque se produce este error. Por aquí también voy a dejar las librerías importadas:

[image: Imagen de las librerias]

Estoy trabajando en eclipse, alguno tiene una idea?

Comment: Es por la versión de xmlbeans que usas prueba usar xmlbeans-2.6.0.

Comment: Creo que te falta poi-examples

Comment: Probé con la xmlbeans-2.6.0 y aun sigue el error

Comment: @BrianHernandez ese problema es de las versiones xmlbeans-2.6.0 y usa el POI version to 3.15

Comment: @RaulCacacho Entonces debo usar la versión 3.15 de POI?

Comment: @BrianHernandez si es que ese es un problema de versiones tienes que buscar la que las dos versiones se entiendan si usas una mas actual que la otra ya no funciona te da ese error de la vesion 3 a la 4 no varia mucho

Comment: @RaulCacacho Esta bien, voy a probar, ahora te cuento

Comment: @RaulCacacho Era exactamente eso, Solucionado el error. Gracias por ayudar!!